# Bash shell tab completion, don't expand the ~

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key a lot when I use the shell (bash).

But I'm getting annoyed that `~` always gets expanded to `/home/"user"`. I don't think it's always been like this; is there any way to stop this behaviour?

An example:

1. `cj@zap:~$ ls ~/`
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. `cj@zap:~$ ls /home/cj/`

I would like to continue to have `~/` and not end up with `/home/cj/`.

Comment: "I don't think it always has been like this." - Programmable completion overrides the readline setting `set expand-tilde off` (default or set in `~/.inputrc`).

Comment: "bind -v | grep tilde" returns "set expand-tilde off" ... so I don't think it will help.

Comment: You might have a look at `shopt -p direxpand`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disabling tilde expansion is quick and painless. Open up `~/.bashrc` and insert this:

```
_expand()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This will override the expand function from `/etc/bash_completion`. I'd recommend commenting on what it does above the function in case you want the expansion back in the future. Changes will take effect in a new instance.

Comment: though `_expand(){ true; }` is shorter :)

Comment: would it not be `_expand(){ false; }`? @tig

Comment: @John: no it should be true. `true` returns successful result and successful result is 0, so `return 0` is equal to `true` in exit status, and `return 1` is equal to `false`. just try `true; echo $?` and `false; echo $?`.

Comment: @tig too much programming has confused me... http://codepad.org/Frb3RyAN    Similarly, you find this in lots of code (see top): http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~tingting/DS_mid_solution.pdf   I would assume it's switched up in the GNU tools to indicate a more realistic meaning, i.e. "True, the program ran successfully" or "false -- the program ran incorrectly".

Comment: @John: that is ok :), «Even John T can be wrong» (don't be offended :) )

Comment: @tig I never use those GNU tools to be honest, I didn't know they were separate binaries instead of bash builtins LOL. I was thinking they must've been out of there mind to do it backwards...

Comment: Or just: `_expand() { :; }`.

Answer (score 7):

With newer bash_completion it seems you also need to override __expand_tilde_by_ref:

```
__expand_tilde_by_ref() {
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more compactly:

```
_expand() { :; }
```

...as ":" is a shell built-in equivalent to "true" :-)

Answer (score 1):

A more precise customization would be

```
_filedir_xspec () { :; }
```