# How to expand * on Bash command line

Tags: bash, autocomplete, globbing

I understand that if you type `ls *` it is actually expanded to `ls a b c` when the current directly has files `a`, `b` and `c`.

I was wondering if there is a way to expand this before I hit enter. Similar to how [Ctrl+X](http://taint.org/2005/05/04/004902a.html) works, or [tab complete](https://superuser.com/questions/95653/bash-shell-tab-completion-dont-expand-the) works.

So to make myself clear

```
$ ls *
<press magic key>
$ ls a b c
```

in a similar way to:

```
$ ls ~/
<press tab>
$ ls /home/username
```

I thought I'd seen this before but I might have been mistaken.

Comment: Well, I know very little but the best I know of is $echo * <ENTER> You could do that before the ls * command. That's not quite hitting tab or a shortcut to expand it of course.

Comment: But perhaps linux users wouldn't do anything like ls * much 'cos it probably isn't necessary with ls, But also globbing behaves differently on different shells so it's not that portable, but when convenient then fine. But in ls's case, not necessary. ls */ lists directories but not so much what ls is designed to do.

Comment: Yeah but @barlop I'm not sure any command has a use case for just expanding `*` and then running it - but the use case for all of them is when you want to expand them all and then edit a few random ones out that are too hard to hit with a regex before you hit enter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `glob-expand-word` function, from man `bash`:

```
The word before point is treated as a pattern for pathname
expansion, and the list of matching file names is inserted,
replacing the word. If a numeric argument is supplied, an
asterisk is appended before pathname expansion.
```

Add something like this to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
Control-x: glob-expand-word
```

So `$ ls *` followed by <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> will expand to `$ ls a b c`, in your example.

Comment: It should already be bound. And Ctrl-x is already bound as a prefix to a bunch of stuff. Do `bind -p | grep 'C-x'` to see them.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @Dennis, it wasn't already bound, but adding it to my .inputrc has. I guess that's Debian's default.

Comment: @Dennis: It's bound to `C-x*` on my system.

Answer (score 28):

In bash, the readline capability is called `glob-expand-word` and is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> by default.

Answer (score 15):

When you are in `vi` mode (`set -o vi`), the "magic key" is <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>. This works with both `bash` and `ksh`.

Comment: Just to be clear to vimmers, first type the asterisk while typing the command line normally, then escape out of edit mode, cursor will locate on the asterisk if you escape immediately, then hit asterisk with the cursor located on the asterisk and the glob will expand and drop you in edit mode again.

Comment: @NeilG There is actually no need type this first asterisk. `ls <Esc>*` would work equally fine.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, @jlliagre. I did some playing and found out there are a few pre-conditions for expansion but having an `*` on the command line is not one of them. The command line has to be somehow ready for typing arguments, so for instance, if you're still typing the command itself and have no preceding space it won't expand. Either way, very convenient and intuitive access to this feature without having to use chords or remember which letter to press if you're in **vi** mode.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ bind -q glob-expand-word
glob-expand-word can be invoked via "\C-x*".

$ bind -q insert-completions
insert-completions can be invoked via "\e*".
```

So to use these we can do

`ls *` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>

or

`ls *` <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>

[Expand complicated lines before hitting enter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4615572)

Comment: This is the best answer because it looks up the exact keybinding, which could be different in different environments.

Comment: No it's not the best answer, @wisbucky, in my case I get `glob-expand-word is not bound to any keys`. What then? The accepted answer explains how to bind to what you want, or the conventional in fact, which is `ctrl-x`. This is a less useful answer added 7 years after the accepted answer and except for mentioning `bind` which is also mentioned in comments to the accepted answer (also written 7 years before this answer) it would otherwise be spam.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to glob-expand-word (\C-x*) is insert-completions (\e*). It works without an asterisk at the end, but it also includes other completions like hidden files. I have rebound both in ~/.inputrc:

```
# insert glob results (\C-x* by default)
"\C-g": glob-expand-word

# insert completion list (\e* by default)
"\ei": insert-completions
```

glob-complete-word (\eg) can be used to convert for example `/System/Library/Launch*/*Finder` to `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist`.